# Sort jobs by JOBID in Slurm

Tags: slurm

In Slurm, I would like to `squeue` the jobs of a given user by sorting them in ascending order according to their JOBID. I tried

`squeue -u username --sort=+JOBID`

but it does not work. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The argument of the `--sort` parameter uses the same letter as the format string in the `--format` option. So your command should be

```
squeue -u username --sort=+i
```